# Nesting multiple div tags inside an li tag

Tags: html, xhtml

Is it possible and valid to nest a `<div>` tag inside an `<li>` tag multiple times?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can nest `<div>` tags inside of each-other and inside of `<li>` tags.

You can also put `<li>` tags in `<ul>` or `<ol>` tags that are inside of `<div>` tags.